# Can you slow down pre-AD time progression in Civ V?

Tags: civilization-5

I find as I play the game that time passes too quickly early on. I did some research and haven't found anyway to modify this. Can it be done?

Comment: That awnser doesn't exactly awnser this at all. It provides strategies. @JasonBerkan

Comment: @RainbowDashDC When you have more rep on the site you're encouraged to prod for more information on that question. The quality of its answer doesn't make this question less of a duplicate.

Comment: @dlras2 so it's suggested I go find some random ways too get rep, in order to get an awnser on a question I have? Seems like a great way to get help.

Comment: @RainbowDashDC Unfortunately you need a small amount of rep (50) to comment on things such as the answer you pointed out. That's just 5 upvotes on a question (preferably non-dupe) or 10 on an answer.

Comment: @dlras2 it took me over a month to get that on SO. I don't see the point of limiting comments.

Comment: @RainbowDashDC - Have you tried the mods listed in Agent86's answer?  Other than changing the pace when you start a game, there's not much else you can do.

Comment: @JasonBerkan I tried the last one but its like dead.

Comment: Possibly related question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62441/is-it-possible-to-globally-slow-down-the-pace-of-research-and-culture-gain-wi?rq=1

Comment: It's a lot easier to earn rep here than it is on SO based on my experience on both sites. And who knows, maybe someone who reads this will go and post a new answer to the original question.